# Rigify errors with different feet levels

Tags: rigify

I'm having issues with the Rigify add-on, I don't get this if I use my own bone structure.

1.) When I copy one side (ctrl-c) to the otherside (Ctrl-shift-v) is doesn't match the foot height exactly. One foot is about 10cm off. it is also missing some random copying keypoints. After hitting "a" I make sure they are all there but they are not. I have to go and tweek the animation on the otherside myself?
[image]
Eh???

2.) When I use the IK, to bend the knees the foot goes through the floor on one foot, and the other stays flat. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

3.) The toe spline is not fixed and bends all over the place. It also does not have an IK sketch property?

Comment: No comments? I'm going to do the rig manually I think

Comment: 1) Have you tried to insert a keyframe first at frame #13, then mirror the pose, and finally replace the keyframe?